# Stopping spot instance temporarily

Tags: amazon-ec2-spot-market

This is about this recent announcement:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/amazon-ec2-spot-instances-stopped-started-similar-to-on-demand-instances/

But I can see a smililar feature introduced in the year 2017

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-spot-can-now-stop-and-start-your-spot-instances/

1) I will like to know the difference between the two announcements.
2) When I tried to stop my spot instance, I got this error:

```
Error stopping instances
You can't stop the Spot Instance 'i-0f298e1710169xxxx' because it is in a fleet, which does not support stop
```

I will like to stop the instance to save cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When capacity is no longer available at your preferred price instance will be terminated. `2017 announcement` allows instances to be stopped in the event of interruption, instead of being terminated with ***maintain*** `interruption behavior` option.

This preserves attached volumes, and when capacity becomes available at preferred price - instance is started up back rather than new instance being spun up.

---

`2020 announcement` allows you to manually stop / start spot instances at will at any time, not just when it is about to be terminated due to no capacity. This feature is available for persistent Spot requests.

`AWS Spot Fleet` takes control over instances lifetime and manages them automatically, so these are not persistent Spot requests and Fleet Spot instances cannot be stopped manually.

To minimize costs you can configure [Spot Fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) max cost, on-demand instance types, allocation strategy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got (your point 2) may be solved with the following.

In this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/cost-optimization-leveraging-ec2-spot-instances/spot-instance-interruptions.html), it can be read:

> This feature *(Spot service stop instead of terminate your Amazon EBS-backed Spot Instances)* is available for **persistent Spot requests** and **Spot Fleets with the maintain fleet option enabled**.

Comment: I believe this refers to when EC2 has to interrupt the instance, not when stopping it manually - i.e. you still can't stop a spot fleet manually, even with the maintain option enabled (it returns the error the OP posted).